# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug'. > java.io.IOException:

Tags: android

whenever I try to run my app i get this error :

**Error:Execution failed for task**

```
 :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug'.
 java.io.IOException: Failed to delete 

 C:\Users\ashis\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\restart-changes.txt**
```

**and here is the output:**

Information:Gradle tasks

> [:app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
>   :app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:incrementalDebugTasks
>   :app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
>   :app:fastDeployDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:coldswapKickerDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to delete C:\Users\ashis\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\restart-changes.txt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 6.761 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Answer (score 77, accepted):

:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug'.
 java.io.IOException: Failed to delete

-- try to clean project and rebuild project.

From @Kael: A clean is performed via Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: (For those who are wondering, that's `Build Menu > Clean Project` and `Build Menu > Rebuild Project`)

Comment: its not working, when i click clean project it shows the same error"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'xxxxxxxxxx\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4'."

Comment: @Prasad: Same here.

Comment: I know it's not the place for it... but THANKS A LOT.

Comment: This happens far too often. Any other way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Rebuild also cleans the project.

Answer (score 32):

Kindly follow these steps:
Goto

```
1>File
2>Settings
3>Build,Execution,Deployment 
4>Instant Run
5>Uncheck (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)
```

So this helped me.

Answer (score 8):

In my situation `Build Menu > Clean Project and Build Menu > Rebuild` did NOT work. Instead I had to delete the `build` folder manually from the `filesystem` (using Finder on `OSX`, Explorer on Win).

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean project and rebuild project from `Build Menu > Clean Project and Build Menu > Rebuild` 
try restarting android studio or use android studio on different user

Answer (score 1):

I had Execution failed for task '`:app:generateDebugBuildConfig`'. error, cleaning and rebuilding project was not working.

1. I added `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` to my `PATH` Environment variable.
2. I closed android studio and `vscode` that I was using for edit project files. (This is very important)
3. I run the project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ..  I solved my problem by deleting `.gradle` file on my project root and rebuilt my project again.

Answer (score 0):

Change this https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip to this  https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip in grable-wrapper.prperties. And then re import the properties. and sync the project.