# Understanding testing libraries versions / dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

I was looking for a while how to find out dependencies among libraries but I didn't find anything. E.g. in my build.gradle is

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
//    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
```

How do I know what versions I can use ? (E.g., is com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0 compatible with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0, etc. ?) Is this somewhere documented ? 
E.g., Android Studio tells me I can use newer version by highlighting the row to yellow and saying the newer version. But if I change it, I end up with configuration that builds if I run tests but doesn't build the app. Or vice versa.

E.g., I get an error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>
> > Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\73.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\69.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\68.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\70.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\71.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\76.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\75.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\74.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\77.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
> >     ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1,
> >     file=C:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\72.jar,
> >     contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}

Comment: Just suggesting, do this search over gradle 3 with AS 3, they changed compile to implementation/api/other one i dont remember

Comment: You can find the solution for this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004549/5219299

Answer (score 9):

I just had this issue too and was able to fix it by removing the build folder from the project and building/running the application afterwards.

Comment: Saved me lots of time. Thank you so much.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks bro